# Android async with gps lead to FC

Tags: android, asynchronous, gps

i got this GPS listener method with async:

```
// ASync Task Begin to perform Billing information
        class performBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements GpsStatus.Listener {

            private Context context;

            private ProgressDialog dialog;

            public performBackgroundTask(Context context) {
                performBackgroundTask.this.context = context;
              }

            protected void onPreExecute() {


                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(main.this, "Info", "GPS kapcsolatra vár...");

            }



            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // write here the code to download or any background task.
                globalconstant.mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                globalconstant.mlocManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
                return null;
            }

//          protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
//               if(dialog!=null)
//                   dialog.dismiss();
//
//          }

            /* GPS kapcsolódás figyelő */
            public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {

                // Log.w("TravellerLog :: ", "l1");
                switch (event) {
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX: 
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    show_sens = show_sens + "- GPS\n";
                    sensors.setText(show_sens);
                    //addGPSListener();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS kapcsolódva!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// this means you found GPS
                                                        // Co-ordinates
                    //myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    myChronometer.start();

                    meres = true;
                    start_button.setText("STOP");
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                    break;
                }
            }
            // GPS
                private void addGPSListener() {
                    globalconstant.db.setVersion(1);
                    globalconstant.db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
                    globalconstant.db.setLockingEnabled(true);

                    final String gps =

                    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GPS_Values ("

                            + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Latitude float(10, 8), Longitude float(10, 8),Accuracy INTEGER,Speed INTEGER,timestamp TIMESTAMP);";
                    globalconstant.db.execSQL(gps);

                    Log.d("FESTIVALE :: ", "Frissítési idő: "
                            + globalconstant.gps_update_value);
                    float f = Float.valueOf(globalconstant.gps_update_value.trim())
                            .floatValue();
                    float update = f * 1000;

                    globalconstant.mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    globalconstant.mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
                    globalconstant.mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, (long) update, 0,
                            globalconstant.mlocListener);
                }

                public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

                    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

                        float szel = (float) loc.getLatitude();
                        float hossz = (float) loc.getLongitude();
                        int horiAcc = (int) (loc.getAccuracy());
                        // int speed=(int) ((loc.getSpeed()*3600)/1000); //sebesség km/h-ban
                        int speed = 0;

                        if (loc.hasSpeed()) {
                            speed = (int) ((loc.getSpeed() * 3600) / 1000); // sebesség
                                                                            // km/h-ban
                        } else {
                            speed = 0;
                        }

                        String test = String.format("%.08f", szel);
                        String test2 = String.format("%.08f", hossz);

//                      Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(main.this, Locale.getDefault());
//                      try {
//                          List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(szel, hossz,
//                                  1);
//                          city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
//                      } catch (IOException e) {
//                          e.printStackTrace();
//                      }

                        ContentValues gps_values = new ContentValues();

                        gps_values.put("Latitude", test);
                        gps_values.put("Longitude", test2);
                        gps_values.put("Accuracy", horiAcc);
                        gps_values.put("Speed", speed);
                        //gps_values.put("City", city);

                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

                        gps_values.put("timestamp", dateFormat.format(date));

                        try {
                            globalconstant.db.beginTransaction();
                            globalconstant.db.insert("GPS_Values", null, gps_values);
                            globalconstant.db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                        } finally {
                            globalconstant.db.endTransaction();
                        }

                        Log.d("FESTIVALE :: ", "Hely" + test + ", " + test2 + " , "
                                + horiAcc + " , " + speed);
                        // String Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitude = "
                        // + loc.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude = " + loc.getLongitude();

                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hely" +test + "\n" +
                        // test2 + "\n" + horiAcc + "\n" +speed + "\n" +city,
                        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        // .show();

                    }

                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                switch (which) {
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                    // show gps otions
                                    Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(
                                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                    startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
                                    break;

                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(main.this);
                        builder.setMessage("A GPS nincs aktiválva!\nAktiválja most?")
                                .setPositiveButton("Aktivál", dialogClickListener)
                                .setNegativeButton("Nem", dialogClickListener).show();
                    }

                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                    }

                }// gps vége

        }
```

and i got error:

```
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:1281)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:1281)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.location.LocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(LocationManager.java:1320)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.eyecom.festivale.main$performBackgroundTask.doInBackground(main.java:800)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.eyecom.festivale.main$performBackgroundTask.doInBackground(main.java:1)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-26 12:59:10.299: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  ... 4 more
```

i really dont know what to do, thas why i posted it for here.
Please give me some advice/idea/answer how to fix this...
You can edit my code if you want!
Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: On first look, I'd say your `AsyncTask` should not be implementing the GPSStatus.Listener. Probably your Activity should.

Comment: i dont know exactly the asyc thats why i need a 'edit' help maybe...